# Provide a bulk-rollback mechanism for all features that can be bulk-approved

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, moderator-tools, rollbacks

On Programmers, thanks to the [shiny new badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484/149432) no doubt, dozens of tag wikis were suggested that directly copied Wikipedia and Stack Overflow's tag wikis. This violates the attribution requirement of the CC-BY-SA license, and generally makes for a really crappy tag wiki.

Someone with approval access to the suggested edit queue approved these en masse without checking to see if the content was plagiarized or copied. This presents a problem, as we can't have plagiarized or copyright-violating content on the site.

Unfortunately, what took the approver about 2 minutes to do can't be easily undone: we have to go back into each tag wiki, blank out the full description, and come up with a dummy tag wiki excerpt (since you can't save a tag wiki with a blank excerpt).

This is—for lack of a better word—*insane*. I get the value and draw of having low-friction approval mechanisms, but there needs to be a way to easily roll it back when people get it really, really wrong.

Please, think of the <strike>children</strike> mods: don't let bulk approvals exist without an appropriate bulk rollback mechanism.

Comment: Related: [How to prevent users applying a policy without agreement?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110726/how-to-prevent-users-applying-a-policy-without-agreement)

Comment: Also, it could be a bit easier to see which tag wikis recently changed. (There is the [Suggested edits Dashboard](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits), but it is only for 10k-users, and only shows suggested edits - and not only tag wikis.)

Comment: (*I don't have access to the suggested edits queue*) When you say "bulk approved", is there an "Approve All" type button?  Or are you saying someone just quickly clicked through them all ("Approve", "Approve", "Approve",..., done)?

Comment: @jadarnel27 The latter. If only it were that easy to roll back.

Comment: This could probably be (mostly) solved by requiring *two people* to approve edits (as is currently required on Stack Overflow)

Comment: Would be nice even to give an 8 hour buffer for tag wikis to mods and let them pass back to the 5k/20k view if they let it slip by