# Rethinking/discussing privileges

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

What are privileges for?

Privileges are in place so that new users get to know the system and not spam closevotes everywhere, delete random posts, make incorrect edits, downvote everything, etc.

With that said, I think there should be some changes to the privilege system. Here's our current system, and how I think it could be improved:

- 10 rep: images, multiple links, answer protected questions, ask/answer more quickly, review, community wiki
- I think that these privileges are good, mostly. No image/link/answer/question spam from new users. Maybe review should be a bit higher; I don't think by 10 rep one would know enough about the system to review. (**proposal**: review -> 40)
- 15 rep: upvote, flag
- Upvote might need to be raised just a bit higher, maybe 25. One answer of your accepted and now you can upvote? Flagging is good here. (**proposal**: upvote -> 25)
- 20 rep: chat
- This one's okay as it is. We don't want too many chat-question-spammers here.
- 50 rep: comment
- This one needs to be lowered. This is the source of many not-an-answer answers and I think commenting can't be too harmful. (**proposal**: comment -> 25)
- 75 rep: bounties
- The minimum bounty amount is 50. 75 isn't that far away from 50. This one's good.
- 100 rep: edit CW, create chatrooms
- Community Wiki is meant to be edited by the community, but we don't want spam. Perfect rep level for this. Chatrooms are easily cleaned up if incorrectly created, too.
- 125 rep: downvote
- I agree with this one. With the association bonus, you must participate a bit before you can -1. That would get you to understand the site better.
- 200 rep: reduce ads
- Good incentive to get more rep. :D
- 250 rep: view closevotes on your own question
- I might even go so far as to say this should be available from 1 rep. You should be able to know when someone wants to close your question. However, users might say "HEY DON'T CLOSE ME" so not that low. (**proposal**: view closevotes on self -> 50)
- 500 rep: retag
- I think by, say, 300 rep, you should know what tags are for and how to use them. (**proposal**: retag -> 300)
- 1k rep: view vote count, expanded usercard, create gallery chatrooms
- I completely disagree with this one. The vote count should be available from something like 150 rep. I know it's "expensive," but it really can't be too bad. I barely ever use it anyway. For the usercard, it's just a nice little thing for fun, pretty much. Gallery chatrooms: if you can create normal chatrooms, why can't you create gallery ones? (**proposals**: vote count -> 150, gallery chatrooms -> 150)
- 1.5k rep: create tags
- Pretty hefty amount between retagging and creating tags. Once you know the tag system enough to retag, shouldn't you know enough to create tags, too? (**proposal**: create tags -> 600)
- 2k rep: edit
- Perfect. You need to be trusted quite a bit to edit everything.
- 2.5k rep: Create synonyms
- Lower this one! If you have a score of 5 or more on the tag that should prove you know enough. (**proposal**: synonymize -> 1k)
- 3k rep: Vote to close
- Closing is a pretty big thing. I think the rep for this is perfect as it is.
- 5k rep: approve tag wiki edits
- Woah, why so far from the 2k for editing? What makes tag wikis any different? (**proposal**: tag wiki edits -> 2.5k)
- 10k rep: handle flags, vote to (un)delete, view deleted, (a whole bunch of lists)
- Alright. Handling flags: by 10k rep this is a well earned privilege. Vote to (un)delete: also good. Deletion is really important because it's gone. Except for other 10ks, that is. View deleted: Hey, what's the harm in letting people see deleted posts? This one's WAY too high. View tons of lists: Yeah, this one's okay. (**proposal**: view deleted -> 1k)
- 15k rep: protect
- Protecting is a big thing. This one's good.
- 20k rep: trusted user
- Everything in here I agree with except for editing tag wiki without approval. You can edit posts 18 thousand rep before! (**proposal**: edit tag wiki without approval -> 2.5k)

---

We have [a theory of moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). Let's follow it.

Comment: Lots of proposals, but I don't see reasoning behind them. Please explain the reasoning behind the change and how it would help.

Comment: @Oded Read the big list. It explains everything in the second level of indentation.

Comment: Lowering the threshold on certain types of edits (most notably the tag wikis) would introduce far more poor edits than the system can currently keep up with.

Comment: @Makoto That's the only thing I lowered. Shouldn't you be trusted to edit tag wiki if you can edit posts, which are in my opinion far more important?

Comment: There are many bits and bobs in there which have already been discussed in separate questions. Some of them dismissed before. I'm not entirely sure if this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: [I](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149621/175248) [would](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155561/175248) [think](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137784/175248) [not.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122038/175248)

Comment: @Makoto That has nothing to do with tag wikis.

Comment: I disagree.  My gut feeling tells me that if we lower the threshold for tag wiki edits, we'll get similar pangs of abuse and poor edits, and I don't think that the system can keep up with that yet.

Comment: I think upvote should be allowed from rep 1, at least for one's own questions. Now noobs can't upvote you when you answer their question.

Comment: Whoa, view deleted at *1k*?  That's *waaay* to low.  I think it's fine the way it is.  Also, not sure if you know this, but on smaller sites like [Chess.SE](http://chess.stackexchange.com/privileges) the reputation limits are lower.  500 to VTC, 1k to edit, etc.

Comment: I'm pretty happy with SO as it is. Time spent tweaking the scores would be better spent on moderating what's already there (either manually, or by providing better tools). Changing the rules will just make new problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please make it harder, not easier, to mess with tag wikis, especially to create them from scratch. The edit queue is full of unattributed copies and other horrors.

Answer (score 5):

> - 10k rep: handle flags, vote to (un)delete, view deleted, (a whole bunch of lists)
>
>   - Alright. Handling flags: by 10k rep this is a well earned privilege. Vote to (un)delete: also good. Deletion is really important because it's gone. Except for other 10ks, that is. View deleted: Hey, what's the harm in letting people see deleted posts? This one's WAY too high. View tons of lists: Yeah, this one's okay. (**proposal**: view deleted -> 1k)

Given that a 1k user can't actually do anything with a deleted post, what's the point in seeing them?

This would only add noise to the 1-9k user's experience.