# Copying profanities and obscene words on Meta

Tags: discussion, meta, profanity

Let's settle this once and for all. When discussing posts or comments (on any Meta site), is it a problem to copy profanities and obscene words from that post or comment if relevant to the discussion?

There are two extremes:

1. No profanities: they should be removed/censored, to prevent corporate firewalls from filtering Stack Exchange sites based on these profane words.
2. Profanities are not an issue: it is not a Stack Exchange policy to remove/censor them. Leave them in the posts and respect the author's will and intent.

I would go with number 1 just to be on the safe side, although I personally don't like it.

---

This question is a direct result of the editing and reverting done on [an answer to *Why was this edit approved?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/172684/revisions) which, due to that, was locked.

Comment: You could compromise and add the sweariness in a 'spoiler' area: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396 although personally i think if your Meta question is directly about a piece of naughty language then it kind of makes sense to include it in the question itself, otherwise how will people know what you're referring to? That's like me saying "I am offended when people use the word {CENSORED}"

Comment: Hasn't this been settled once and for all like 10 times already? Don't use those words unless it's necessary, but sometimes it is necessary.

Comment: @JonW That, and it wouldn't help against the 'corporate firewalls filtering profane sites' issue, as the text is technically still there. You just don't see it.

Comment: @mmyers If it is, the search on 'profane', 'profanity', 'obscene' on Meta did not turn it up. Then you have a link to it, right?

Comment: FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites

Comment: @mmyers That's clearly not the same. All questions I could find (this one included) are about using profanities in normal conversations. _Of course that's not done._ I'm asking about discussing them. Also, your link is not a source for "don't use those words unless it's necessary, but sometimes it is necessary" in a meta discussion.

Comment: @Virtlink can you cheat and add some random tags around some of the letters in the particular word? You know, like adding an `<i>` around the 'F' in that word? Or is that a bit hacky (and may not actually work anyway).

Comment: If you're worried about corporate filters, or the searchability or the word, just add [zero-width spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) between the letters. It *should* be enough to fool searches and filters.

Comment: Also don't refer to yourself in the third person: "the original author". It seems disingenuous.

Comment: It's worth noting that while it may be important for someone to get to a programming question that happens to have some profanity in it somewhere, it's not really a problem for a corporate firewall to filter a meta question about how to handle a case of vulgarity.  Just view that meta question when you get home.

Comment: I deleted about half of the comments here because they were not going anywhere useful. IMHO, this is a subtly different (and considerably more specific) scenario than what was addressed in the FAQ that @mmyers links to - if you disagree with my answer, post your own and include your rationale.

Answer (score 27):

Unless you *need* it, don't use it. If you *need* it, don't worry about it.

The example that prompted this didn't need it - the vulgarity in question was plainly visible *in the edit the OP linked to!*

An example of "need" might be discussing a potential profanity filter, or perhaps the vulgar name of a [tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110726/how-to-prevent-users-applying-a-policy-without-agreement) or [language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainf-ck-offensive). Even then, *try* to keep it professional; vulgarity for vulgarity's sake is what YouTube comments are for.

I've cleaned up the answer you linked to and unlocked it.

Comment: I agree that it is not _needed_ in this case, but apparently not everyone agrees when it is needed and when not. Your removed it, but your colleague moderator casperOne previously reinstated it. What do you suggest when moderators cannot agree on the need? _Don't_ edit to prevent edit wars, or _do_ edit for other reasons?

Comment: @Virtlink `What do you suggest when moderators cannot agree on the need?`  You create a new meta question to discuss exactly that.  See [this example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172734/copying-profanities-and-obscene-words-on-meta)  Mods don't always need to agree, and regular users can disagree with mods.  Meta *exists* to sort out such issues.

Comment: @Servy Maybe you missed it but your comment is under that very post you linked. Indeed, that's my question and I am asking Shog9 for an answer.

Comment: I didn't remove it, @Virtlink - I just left my opinion in the comments. Since that wasn't respected, I've gone ahead and elaborated on my reasoning here, and reverted back to the original edit (sorry for stomping on your subsequent edit in the process though). If you feel *strongly* that the quote helps the answer in some way, go ahead and revert - but be prepared to explain *why* it's necessary.

Comment: @Virtlink That was intentional.  I was trying to be funny.  When mods disagree they do *exactly what they're doing right now*, they talk about it in a new meta question, publicly, so the rest of the community can contribute as well.  The community then comes to a consensus on what they feel should be done, and a mod (or the community itself) ensures that that action is taken.

Comment: For the general philosophy behind this, see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/

Comment: @Servy Sorry I didn't get that, but I agree with you. Issues should be discussed and not end up edit/revert on another user's post. That's why I asked this question, to open the discussion and get a relatively clear-cut line of when it profanities are allowed and when not. And what to do when in doubt. Benefits not only mods but also other users that edit posts here.

Answer (score -11):

**There is one single Meta post that covers this:**

Stack Exchange policy was given by Jeff, one of the founders, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24206/13295).

The pertinent text that disallows obscenities:

> **You will censor it, or we will censor you. Your choice.**

Another link [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/13295).

Comment: The new leader of SE, fortunately, seems to have a different policy.

Comment: Isn't that about the SE software censoring words (or flagging the post), if you don't censor it? That doesn't apply here. Also, it is the 28th least downvoted Jeff Atwood answer (of all 4409 answers), so it doesn't really seem community accepted IMO.

Comment: @Virtlink, no, it's not about the SE software.

Comment: The most *relevant* discussion is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites - and even that's not meta enough to cover the case of vulgar language *quoted* or *cited* in meta discussions of vulgar language being used elsewhere on SE. Both of the discussions I linked to in my answer (one of which you linked to above) required that the *specific* terms in question be identified *so that folks could know what they were even discussing* - at some point, that becomes unavoidable. But *up to that point*, it's worth trying to avoid unnecessary vulgarity.

Comment: @Shog9 instead of confusing meta readers with contradictory stuff spread over multiple discussions, why not just **add an authoritative statement on "party line" into [meta-tag:profanity] tag wiki**?

Comment: Fair enough, @gnat - done.