# What's wrong with asking if there are any resources that cover a particular topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic

I asked if anyone knew of a [table of programming languages by grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6496452/111327), and the question was closed as "not a real question." I don't understand what is wrong with my question. It is specific and answerable (either "Yes, the URL is..." or "No, because..."). Why do people think it's off-topic?

Comment: Does this have merit in the land of CSTheory?

Comment: I think it is a better fit for programmers, and migrated.

Comment: @jcolebrand: I would think so, but I'm not the expert, hence the question :)

Comment: @jcolebrand No. Classification of programming languages by grammar is not a research topic.

Comment: @Gilles ~ I figured that, but was thinking since grammar is inherently a research topic (I for one don't use it in my day job, I use the outcome of the grammar in my day job) that it _might_ be something those guys would at least know of a _resource of_

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be migrated to programmers.stackexchange.com, but I think it is not off topic.

Comment: advice about migration is bad one, see **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)**

Comment: @gnat: This post is two years old.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know. Added comment so that anyone stumbling upon it, even accidentally (like I did) would be fully aware that advice given in it has been considered harmful long before it was posted - canonical _toilet bowl_ post has been written three years ago (and still remains actual)