# Bulk Migration or deletion of some polls questions

Tags: discussion, migration

A look at the 651 questions tagged [polls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polls) shows many which would be better off <strike>at prog.se or</strike> deleted.

My point is whether *Would it be better if a mod look at this list and **do them all at one go** or should we **individually flag or vote to close/delete them**?*

Some random examples which are not related to coding per se

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63668/confessions-of-your-worst-wtf-moment

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201189/what-do-you-do-to-keep-learning

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490/best-open-source-project-hosting-site

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157319/do-you-have-a-hobby-development-project

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105049/what-are-the-best-design-patterns-books-you-have-read-closed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598/what-is-the-worst-interviewee-answer-closed

Comment: Maybe just close them, rather than ask for migration: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106727/38765

Comment: No. Poll questions are off topic on Programmers just as they are off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've voted to close some of the examples listed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To the suggestion that migration is an option (especially to Programmers.SE and not instead to some dark nexus of evil questions), I have only one thing to say:

[image: Noooooooo]

Poll and "fun" questions [aren't on-topic anywhere on the network](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), so please get it out of your mind that they can be migrated somewhere successfully. And Programmers.SE is [not Stack Overflow's toilet bowl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl).

If you don't want them on Stack Overflow, they should be closed, locked, and/or deleted. I can't imagine flagging every single question in the list is a productive use of already over-worked moderators' time, and deleting 600+ questions at once just because they have a specific tag on them seems incredibly risky.

So I'm of the mind that they should just be deleted or locked as people run into them organically. Many of them are months or years old: they aren't harming anyone by just staying put for a little while longer while they get evaluated individually.

Comment: They shouldn't be deleted, they just need to be closed and locked, and the "This is from early in the history of SO and isn't considered on-topic any more" disclaimer added.

Comment: My question was mainly about "bulk deletion v individual flagging". I've updated my question to clarify.

Comment: @JoseK Under no circumstances is Programmers.SE an option for crappy poll questions. Your two choices are lock or delete.

Comment: I'd downvote if it weren't for the image. Burninate the questions ASAP!