# What Markdown formatting features are available for Bounty remarks?

Tags: support, status-completed, bounties, markdown

According to the [community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), backticks and inline links are available for the bounty remark.

What other formatting features of Markdown are also supported on Bounty remarks?

Comment: Aha - Just confirmed that *italic* (`*text*`)` formatting is also supported. Line breaks are also preserved.

Comment: Indeed, [your emphasis and line breaks](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv48u.png) look okay, and `[link](url)` [worked fine for me once](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnk2b.png) too.

Comment: I also wondered, does adding bounties count towards the edit count for CW mode?

Comment: @Rob I couldn't find any existing questions about that, but [bounties don't appear in PostHistoryTypes](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/59723/60511/), so I'm guessing no, they don't count.

Comment: And I found the reference for `\`code\`` being supported in Frédéric comment in [Can we have a way to edit bounty text?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text).

Comment: Hmmm, too bad Jeff deleted your earlier proof that quotes did work. I just posted a bounty remark that [looked fine in the question preview](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8QROt.png), but [not so much in the final result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hsnzY.png)! Wish I could upvote [Can we have a way to edit bounty text?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text) twice!

Comment: @Arjan, my earlier proof showed [full markdown support](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1kxQC.png). However, the SE team decided to only allow the basic markdown support (See Geoff's answer).

Comment: Indeed, @Rob, I can see that deleted answer, but thanks for posting the image in [a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text/122821#comment326791_122821) too! I guess full-blown Markdown might not be needed, though I've not seen any abuse yet—and your [suggested limitation](http://jsfiddle.net/UBsYh/show/) should have been fine too! But not being able to edit, especially as support suddenly changed, is a pity though!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Bounty notices will support our Markdown mini format, using the same format as we allow for comments, with the addition of paragraph breaks.  The following will be allowed:

```
_italic_ and **bold** text,
inline `code in backticks`,
and [basic links](http://example.com).

and paragraph breaks
```

Which would produce:

> *italic* and **bold** text,
> inline `code in backticks`,
> and [basic links](http://example.com).
>
> and paragraph breaks

Paragraph breaks (double-line) [are rendered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124016/line-breaks-paragraphs-for-bounty-text), but not single-line breaks. Support for paragraph breaks was added in February 2020.

If you want additional formatting, you'll need to get creative. For example, you could implement some simple bullet points with some Unicode characters:

> Some simple pseudo-bullet points:
>
> ⠀⠀●⠀First point
>
> ⠀⠀●⠀Second point
>
> ⠀⠀⠀⠀●⠀First sub-point: Note, however, that any lines which are wrapped within the bullet point will not be indented. So, this won't look the same as an actual unordered list.

The text used for the above pseudo-bullet point example is:

```
Some simple pseudo-bullet points:

⠀⠀●⠀First point

⠀⠀●⠀Second point

⠀⠀⠀⠀●⠀First sub-point: Note, however, that any lines which are wrapped within the bullet point will not be indented. So, this won't look the same as an actual unordered list.
```

Comment: So, Links are automatically converted as well? Example of link in a comment: http://s.tk/

Comment: Comments also allow for the `[tag:feature-request]`, [tag:feature-request] thingy. Not that I ever used those, but curious: are they supported too?

Comment: Note that title attributes (that are rendered as hover text for the link) are part of the [advanced links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-links "All the cool people use them!") and so putting them in a bounty notice will mangle the text.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a "help" link next to the bounty notice input box, like there is for comment input boxes.