# Maximum image width not applied in bounty messages (.question-status)

Tags: bug, status-declined, bounties, bounty-remarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What markdown formatting features are available for Bounty remarks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/what-markdown-formatting-features-are-available-for-bounty-remarks)

Images in posts (`.post-text img`) have a `max-width` of `100%`.

> [image]

This isn't yet applied to the new possibility of images in bounty messages (`.question-status img`).

> [image]

Comment: Jimmy Wales looks extra menacing peeping out from behind the linked questions list.

Comment: Er. Is it intended that you can include images in bounty messages?

Comment: *Related:* [What markdown formatting features are available for Bounty remarks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/what-markdown-formatting-features-are-available-for-bounty-remarks) @MichaelMrozek See comments.

Comment: well THANKS For ruining everyone's fun .... THANKS :)