# When did Stack Overflow start advertising for Wikipedia?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What markdown formatting features are available for Bounty remarks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/what-markdown-formatting-features-are-available-for-bounty-remarks)

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) has a bounty that looks like the following on my screen:

[image: example]

What's the deal?

Comment: [Blame Jeremy Banks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120333/maximum-image-width-not-applied-in-bounty-messages-question-status).

Comment: @Geoff what does "status-completed" mean in this case? It looks like the bounty was refunded, but is the loophole still open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you open a bounty, you can type in a message for why you're opening the bounty. Jeremy Banks typed that in as their message. It has nothing to do with Stack Overflow, they do not endorse it, it is not an advertisement from them.

Answer (score 6):

Bounty notices will support our markdown mini format using the same format as we allow for comments.  The following will be allowed:

```
_italic_ and **bold** text,
inline `code in backticks`,
and [basic links](http://example.com).
```

Answer (score 3):

I flagged it for moderation with the following comment:

> Using a bounty to post advertising on an obviously popular question is wholly inappropriate, and harms the community.  Wikimedia may be a good cause, but that is no excuse to post blatant advertising in this, or any other field of the question.

If, however, Stack Exchange, LLC, permits bounty-based advertising on any question, then I will be more than happy to put my reputation to use in an advertising campaign.  I can put up to 3 seven-day advertisements on popular questions at once for a mere 150 rep per weekly campaign.  Very reasonably priced!

I love this idea, it's so much cheaper than the advertising program Stack Exchange runs, and it's much more front-and-center for even high-reputation users.  Much larger advertising can be used, and even a flickering gif.  Very, very cool!

Comment: To be clear, I used the Wikipedia ads because [they've become an internet meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/blog/in-the-media/jimmy-wales-sees-all), not because I meant to support the foundation. I agree that such advertising should not be allowed.

Comment: It's not so much advertising, he was just trying to prove a bug. This isn't a common issue and of course advertising should be taken care of whether it occurs inside a bounty or message or any other regular answer, question, or comment.

Comment: @Cleanupcareer-development Interesting that every time you posted it, even in the relevant meta question, you went to the effort to link directly to the wikimedia donation page.

Comment: @AdamDavis It'd be sloppy to do otherwise.

Comment: casperOne's removed it.

Comment: This opens up [whole new worlds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116891/will-stack-overflow-boycott-godaddy-because-of-their-support-for-sopa), man.

Comment: @AdamDavis I figured with this being something only higher rep users could abuse, maybe it wouldn't turn into a problem. I entertained that foolish hope for nearly a whole hour

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Yeah, no dice.  I'm hoping they choose to simply let moderation deal with it to see if it becomes a real problem.  But seriously, do we really need all that functionality in a bounty reason?

Comment: Aw, someone removed my bounty on the godaddy sopa question!  And it still hasn't been status-completed.  Hmph.

Comment: @Cleanupcareer-development: I was hoping that was the case - you could have just flagged it to let us know you were simply trying to prove a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I verified that you can put images in bounty reasons. This *probably* isn't intentional, and the case above is almost certainly abuse.

[image: unicorn bounties]

(Note that in this case I refunded the bounty - this was just a test.)

We'll have to wait and see what the official response is, but image markdown probably wasn't supposed to be enabled in bounties.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/what-markdown-formatting-features-are-available-for-bounty-remarks