# What should I do if I make a typo in my bounty text?

Tags: support, flags, bounties

I know I can't edit it myself (there is a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-custom-message) to enable this).

I just raised a custom moderator flag with an explanation and the replacement bounty text, but I don't want to waste their time if they can't modify it or the flag is not an appropriate way to tell them.

What's the procedure here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we have a way to edit bounty custom message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-custom-message) Suggested as the former suggested duplicates have themselves been closed as duplicates of this one.

Comment: @Joachim Thanks, but nope, that's really a feature request for a way to edit bounties. This question is acknowledging no such feature exists right now, so what to do in the meantime (which surprisingly none of the answers to that question cover).

Comment: @Justin / (@TheAmplitwist) Thanks, but see above. That question has no answers unfortunately, and the dupe target is not quite the question I'm asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/282094)  and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119684/282094 - lack of an answer (for this or the other duplicates) doesn't mean it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @Rob Agreed, this could be a dupe of a question with no answers (although wouldn't they become a dupe of this because this has a good answer?). I was responding "nope" to the "Does this answer your question?" - those questions & answers are more "Can I edit/how can I edit the bounty" - I already know I can't edit it, so those questions aren't so useful (the "how can I edit" would be useful but has no answers and inconclusive ephemeral comments). Updated my post to clarify.

Comment: Greedo, when you are satisfied with whatever answer you get, and have done appropriate research with links to prove it, **you** can edit the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/282094) and answer this question there; because the answer *should* be there. --- Mention that people can use the Q&A edit box to edit the text for their bounty (but as mentioned in the bounty markdown link, also included) **if** they understand the differences (including double spacing between paragraphs). --- There are several rules about what constitutes a duplicate, that's a different FAQ. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's a minor typo, live with your shame.  (I kid, I kid).

We can't edit bounties. In *theory*, we *could* refund it and have you post a bounty again, but in general, unless there's extraordinary circumstances, your options are limited.

In practice, you could probably throw a comment under your question to clarify the typos, which probably would be a reasonable and simple way to do it

Comment: Will the new bounty be the same as the first one or will it be double the previous one?

Comment: It would be the same, but we don't generally refund bounties without a great reason. Say if you mispelled duck in a fishy way, and wrote a very apologetic flag...

Comment: Yeah, I mean it's fine, not an embarrassing mistake luckily. The [bounty reads](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/273733/146810) "concern line" rather than "command line" and "formats if package" instead of "formats of package" (phone autocorrect) but from context I guess it's clear enough. Would still be preferable to fix.

Comment: could throw a comment under your question pointing it out :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Good idea!