# Add a grace period for editing bounty messages

Tags: feature-request, edits, bounties, bounty-remarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a way to edit bounty text?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text)

I think there should be a grace period for editing the message added to a bounty offering, similar to the 5 minutes grace period on editing comments.

I do not think that it should be possible to change the bounty reason during this period, but it would be nice to be able to correct stupid spelling mistakes like this one:

[image]

Once the period - say 5 minutes - is up, then the message would no longer be editable, in the same way that comments are not now.

Edit: In the above case, I flagged it for a moderator, and the flag was rightly declined for the reason Chris gives in the comments (namely that mods can only refund a bounty, not edit it).  If I had the ability to edit the message that useless flag could have been avoided.

Comment: @Dennis - the only "fixing" we can do is refund the bounty so you can restart it. Something we'd only want to do for a major mistake, not a typo.

Comment: @ChrisF: I know, and I agree completely. That's why I said *I wouldn't worry about the typo. In general, ...*.

Comment: @ChrisF - I wish I'd read that before submitting the flag!  But that does illustrate why a short-lived edit feature would be handy.

Comment: Well on a site with few flags you might find a friendly moderator. I would expect the SO mods to just clear the flag and do nothing.