# Comments on bounty once it has been started

Tags: feature-request, comments, bounties

It would be useful to be able to have comments on a bounty once it has started so that:

- The bounty poster can add updates if they want to clarify what they are looking for. (This would be less needed if it was possible to [edit the bounty message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text))
- People can ask the bounty poster to clarify what they are looking for.

I've just posted a bounty and I'd like to add something to the message. The only option at the moment is to add comments to the question which I'm reluctant to do as the will not be relevant to the question once the bounty has been awarded.

Answer (score 1):

I think you grasp the idea of the bounty system in a wrong way.

Bounty has no content of its own. Its purpose is to attract other users to answer, or award existing answer.

Comments should be made on something substantial, like a question or an answer. (Or other comment)

Like Asad said [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158948/bounty-award-decals-should-link-to-show-bounty-message#comment460109_158948) on other post, the purpose of the bounty additional message it to "explain what you expect from the answer you would award the bounty to". Once the bounty is over, it has no meaning anymore.

If other user want to "ask the bounty poster to clarify what they are looking for" he can use the `@Sam` in comment on the question I believe you will get notification and you'll be able to reply as usual, then you can delete the comments after a while to avoid the noise.

Bottom line, I think that having the ability to edit the bounty custom message will be just enough and I agree it's somethinng that we should have. But commenting on the message is not really required.

Comment: "then you can delete the comments after a while to avoid the noise." That won't happen. Why should comments about a bounty message that will disappear go on the question where they may end up permanently out of context.

Comment: Deleting comments when they become obsolete is totally common and normal, can't see why you're so opposed to this.