# bounty-award decals should link to/show bounty message

Tags: feature-request, bounties, bounty-badges, bounty-remarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add bounty remarks to a question’s revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110003/add-bounty-remarks-to-a-questions-revision-history)

It would be useful to know what a bounty was awarded for. The bounty-award decal should either link to a page showing the message that was posted requesting the bounty, show it in a tooltip or display it inline on the page when clicked. If [Comments on bounty once it has been started](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158947/comments-on-bounty-once-it-has-been-started) is implemented it should also show those comments.

Comment: IMHO the bounty remarks have no purpose once the bounty has already been awarded. They're just there to explain what you expect from the answer you would award the bounty to.

Comment: Awarded bounties are a signal to the quality of an answer. Why they were awarded is useful information in judging whether they are a useful signal to the reader. If a bounty was awarded for putting forward a particular point of view it's awarding might be less useful as a signal than one that was awarded for creating a balanced answer.