# Bounty custom message disappears after the bounty has been awarded

Tags: discussion, bounties, bounty-remarks

Probably not an issue (and hopefully not a duplicate question), but I just noticed that *bounty custom message disappears after the bounty has been awarded*. Perhaps it could be still accessible as a tooltip on the awarded bounty icon?

Also there is no *bounty-note/bounty[-custom]-message/bounty-remark* tag. What's the actual name for it anyways?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: (and/or [bounty-award decals should link to/show bounty message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158948))

Comment: should the 2nd question (about the tags) be a separate question?

Comment: @Geo: What do you mean by tags? They are called bounty remarks, and you seem to have gotten that tag onto the question...

Comment: ok, I thought that remarks and custom message were different things

Comment: @Geo: I've updated the excerpt for that tag to be more straight-forward.