# Allow bounty owners to comment on questions they've placed a bounty on, even if they have less than 50 reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, comments, bounties

After offering a bounty to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/716044/405086), I realize that I cannot comment on the question because I no longer have the required reputation.

Is it possible to change this behavior, so that the bounty owner can **comment only on the post with the bounty irrespective of their reputation**? While bounty owners are told that they'll lose privileges at the time they place a bounty, it makes sense to allow them to interact with potential answerers/commentators to help solve the problem, or at least provide additional information.

Comment: Makes sense, as you already get partial "OP power" by having notifications for new answers. :)

Comment: Related/alternative suggestion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158947/comments-on-bounty-once-it-has-been-started

Comment: [Same situation at Russian StackOverflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10441/337980)

Comment: Related. But I have not found this feature request before: [Comment on posts that you have an open bounty on, despite reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192403/383809)

Comment: One can be desperate enough to lose the privilege of commenting in general. But being able to comment on the very post you bountied upon — is very different.

Comment: You can always submit a question to your own question.  The comment section isn’t the appropriate location to asking additional questions anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future. We recognize that time and thought was put into this request, but unfortunately, we can't prioritize it at this time.