# Bounty-setter can’t comment on bounty question

Tags: feature-request, bug, comments, bounties, privileges

I know there have been many requests that, once you earn a privilege,
you should keep that privilege forever, even if you drop below
the reputation threshold that granted you that privilege
— especially if you lose the reputation by issuing a bounty. 
I support this request — it seems like a minor code change
to treat privileges like badges, with a bitmap
where bits get set when you reach a threshold and never get unset —
but I know that that request has been consistently declined,
so I’m not making it again.

But I do want to identify an edge case that has not been cited before,
to the best of my recollection. 
This is not a hypothetical scenario; it happened yesterday.

1. Super User question [Since upgrade from Linux 4.6 to (4.7, 4.8),
   %CPU is always 0; the frequency is unknown](https://superuser.com/q/1138045/150988) has been idle for 10 months. 
   (The OP, [Skywalker13](https://superuser.com/users/441117/skywalker13), did edit it 9 months ago. 
   Also, the OP posted an update as an “answer”
   the same day he asked the question, and deleted it less than two hours later.)
2. Yesterday, [User ToYonos](https://superuser.com/users/663451/toyonos) set a bounty of 100 points on the question
   (saying “A detailed canonical answer is required …”,
   although the question doesn’t really have *any* answer
   except “don’t use a current version of Linux;
   find a version that’s old enough that it doesn’t have the problem,
   and use that.”)
3. ToYonos is a 4½-year veteran of Stack Overflow, with over 7K rep there,
   but is relatively new to Super User and has not earned any rep there
   (except for the association bonus).
4. Do the math. 
   ToYonos had 101 rep on Super User, so he had “comment everywhere” privilege. 
   But he spent 100 rep on the bonus, leaving him with only 1
   — so he *lost* the commenting privilege.  …
5. … so he can’t comment on the question where he set the bounty. 
   If he had thought to do so,
   he could have commented on it *before* he created the bounty; now he can’t.

To add insult to injury,

- Two hours after ToYonos started the bounty,
  Super User’s [highest reputation user](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) posted [a comment](https://superuser.com/q/1138045/150988#comment1824671_1138045):

  > @ToYonos: Since you are not the original poster,
  >   could you please give some details about your problem.
  >   and why doesn’t the solution in the post fit your case.

  This is especially ironic since, as I said,
  there *isn’t* a constructive answer.
- ToYonos posted [an answer](https://superuser.com/q/1138045/150988#1244059) (now 10K-only):

  > Sorry I don’t have enough rep here so I will post an answer.
  >
  > The OP seems to have "fix" his issue downgrading to Linux 4.4.33. 
  >   I don’t want this, I’d rather have an explanation and/or a proper solution.
  >
  > My issue is quite the same, `top` giving zeros in `%CPU` and `%MEM` columns,
  >   `cpupower frequency-info` giving the same result.
- Another [highly active SU user](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) zapped a couple of comments:

  > This should have been submitted as a comment.
  >   While you are unable to submit comments until you have 50 reputation.
  >   Commentary submitted as an answer will be deleted by the community.
  >   Answers and questions which are not well received
  >   (comments submitted as an answer are not well received)
  >   count against your ability,
  >   to submit new questions and answers in the future even if they are deleted
  >
  > Since you have an issue, its not possible for us to help you,
  >   so your question will remain unanswered unless you ask your own question. 
  >   I caution you from asking your question as-is
  >   because it lacks enough detail to actually answer it.

  … and ToYonos deleted the answer about half an hour later.

  This is adding insult to injury.

  - As I said, ToYonos *had* over 100 rep,
    and he *had* “comment everywhere” privilege, before he set the bounty.
  - “Since you have an issue, its not possible for us to help you, …” 
    Huh?  Why not? 
    ToYonos isn’t asking people to answer his answer;
    he’s asking them to answer ***Skywalker13’s question***.
  - “I caution you from asking your question as-is
    because it lacks enough detail to actually answer it.” 
    Yeah, sure, if you look at ToYonos’s “answer” as if it were a question,
    then it’s not answerable. 
    But ToYonos is asking people to answer Skywalker13’s question,
    which is over 150 lines (over 1000 words) long
    (although about 70% of that is output from commands). 
    It seems to be detailed enough.

In summary,

- ToYonos has earned the privilege to post comments. 
  He has earned that and more on Stack Overflow,
  and he subsequently earned it by association on Super User when he joined.
- Arguably, ToYonos has invested more in this question than anybody else. 
  (OK, Skywalker13 (the OP) may have invested more time and energy,
  but ToYonos has invested 100 points of rep.)

You can always comment on your own posts. 
Setting a bounty on a question
should give you enough of a stake in that question
to allow you to comment on that question, as if you had asked it.

---

Related: [Notify user when setting a bounty will revoke a privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11930/195817).

Similar-looking but *not* related:
[Comments on bounty once it has been started](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158947/195817).

Comment: I think he can make a **internal link only answer** which automatically converted to comment and then edit it

Comment: I thought writing comments as answers with the expectation that they will be converted to comments was very much frowned upon.  P.S. What is an ‘‘internal link only answer’’?

Comment: @i-- They remove that abusive behavior as an option.

Comment: Thanks @Scott for pointing this issue out

Comment: Dang! I searched for duplicates, but it turns out that, when you search for “privilege”, it doesn’t give you questions that are *tagged* [privileges] (but don’t otherwise contain the word “privilege”).

Comment: With as much experience ToYonos has are Stackoverflow it doesn't explain the reason he submitted his own question as an answer to that question.  ToYonos either didn't care or sadly didn't know, submitting your own question as an answer, isn't an acceptable answer

Comment: As for submitting another comment as an answer, due to the fact the user doesn't have the privilege to comment, is a horrible suggestion.  That is an abuse of the system, and would not be well received, considering they know now that a question submitted as an answer cannot actually answered.  The proper solution to this particular situation, ask a new question, ToYonos can easily indicate the existing question isn't a duplicate because it has no answers

Comment: I understand but I preferred not ask the same question as it could have been considered a duplicate. A bounty sounded like a cleverer choice, I did not anticipate the lost of the comment privilege.

Comment: @ToYonos: I certainly sympathize with your plight. Whenever somebody posts a question that says “This question is like question *X* except …”, it promptly gets closed as a duplicate of question *X*. People seem to have trouble seeing that Skywalker13’s question has no real answer. Just copy the question without linking to it and you’ll be accused of plagiarism, and also have your question closed. Maybe it would have been better to post a new question, wait a few days, and then start a bounty, but you’re stuck now. Since I have posted your comment as a comment, maybe you’ll get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for you help anyway. I was a tricky situation.