# How do I make a URL appear in a bounty?

Tags: feature-request, support, bounties

I want to add a URL to my Bounty, but isn't clickable.  Is this possible?

Can I edit the bounty text after-the-fact?

[Google Ads doesn't support HTTPS. What alternatives are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3485897/328397)

Comment: Also see [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065) no, bounty text is not editable after the fact.

Comment: And as for editing: [Can we have a way to edit bounty text?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text)