# Why bounty messages cannot include line breaks?

Tags: bug, bounties, accessibility

I published [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470440/is-the-callback-concept-of-programming-existent-in-bash) in Unix & Linux StackExchange.

I've added a bounty with quite a long bounty message. The original bounty message included 3 line breaks so to be comprised of three passages (I've added the line breaks with CTRL+Return/Enter):

> From all I've read so far, a "callback" seems to me as "a function
>   that is being called back after a given event was triggered". So far
>   so good, but I feel a simple, clear example for this in Bash is yet to
>   have been given (an answerer might first need to example an event in
>   Bash).
>
> Either way, example in some current answers seem to me a bit
>   complicated-for-no-good-reason in a way that makes them undidactic or
>   including details that might be uneeded to explain how the callback
>   concept in Bash.
>
> Please do not abstain longevity, if it will make a code example
>   simpler, more rewarding, and inclduing less Bash-keywords
>   (encapsulated behavior) that might not be familiar to Bash newbies and
>   will make the attempt to understand the code example even more
>   confusing and hence undidactic.

**Sadly**, it seems that this site doesn't support line breaks in bounty messages so now the current state is that the bounty message appear as one big block of text which is less [Webily-Accessible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accessibility), and less comfortable or efficient to read:

> From all I've read so far, a "callback" seems to me as "a function
>   that is being called back after a given event was triggered". So far
>   so good, but I feel a simple, clear example for this in Bash is yet to
>   have been given (an answerer might first need to example an event in
>   Bash). Either way, example in some current answers seem to me a bit
>   complicated-for-no-good-reason in a way that makes them undidactic or
>   including details that might be uneeded to explain how the callback
>   concept in Bash. Please do not abstain longevity, if it will make a
>   code example simpler, more rewarding, and inclduing less Bash-keywords
>   (encapsulated behavior) that might not be familiar to Bash newbies and
>   will make the attempt to understand the code example even more
>   confusing and hence undidactic.

I ask the community, first in the context of Web Accessibility, then in the context of general reading comfortability, to add these options:

1. An option to support line breaks (CTRL+Return/Enter) in bounty messages.
2. An option to edit bounty messages (AFAIK, as of 09/23/2018, these cannot be edited).

Comment: Also: [Can we have a way to edit bounty custom message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188/323179)