# How come discussion tag made its way into SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

People get so annoyed at discussion type questions in SO. In fact, hardly any such question survives beyond 10 mins before its inevitably closed. But why then a tag exclusively for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) still exist?

Comment: So that we can watch for questions from the sky and burn with  fire I guess.

Comment: A number were migrated/closed, but it's a good point. Most seem to be close fodder.

Comment: Because we haven't yet gone through and retagged/closed where appropriate. In these cases the tag is helpful for identifying bad questions until it's removed. Not sure if this one has been brought up before though.

Comment: Working on it...

Comment: ♬ *Plays @casperOne's re-tagging montage* ♬

Comment: @Lix You might have to loop it for a little bit.

Comment: Egad, and four synonyms point to it.

Comment: Here's a classic I found...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380739/who-are-the-jeff-atwood-and-joel-spolsky-outside-the-microsoft-universe Currently on page 8, in the 300's

Comment: WOW - [so] used to be sooo different! **That** post wouldn't have lasted 10 seconds today :P

Comment: [Literally, the answer here is jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226750/which-frameworks-abstract-away-the-dom)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By the current site standards, it should *not* be there.  Almost *everything* that has that tag is "Not Constructive" (and in a really bad way) and doesn't currently fit into what is acceptable to the site.

That said, the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag is now **gone**.  I've removed the tag from **469** questions that it was on, and will **never reappear** as the tag has now been **blacklisted**.

A *massive* number of them were old, non-constructive messes with little inbound traffic.  A good number of them were closed as Non Constructive, if not outright deleted.

It's possible that there are some that should be undeleted and/or reopened, and if so, please flag them for moderator attention or bring them up here on meta and we'll review them.
[image: you know what this is]

Comment: Spoons are good for scupping out the eyeballs

Comment: @random I need the pointy parts of the spork to get through the eyelid when they insist on trying to protect themselves.

Comment: @casperOne y'know, it would be nice if SO allowed (approved) bot accounts, like Wikipedia does. Any meta-proposal for that?

Comment: Also: how did you untag them without bumping to the main page?

Comment: @ManishEarth I have super powers =P  Seriously though, there were a number that were closed and/or deleted.

Comment: @casper makes sense..

Comment: Whenever I decide to do a cleanup job on Physics I have to do it bit by bit--to avoid excessive bumps :/

Comment: @ManishEarth SO's homepage is customized, unlike other sites..

Comment: Ohhhh, I was sure Shog9 would take over the dragon! Surprise!

Comment: There is no need of spoons, or forks: Just use microwaves.