# Should Moderator Votes Count For More?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, moderators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add vote weighting for self-nominated Experts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49673/add-vote-weighting-for-self-nominated-experts)

I think that moderator votes on questions should count slightly more than non-moderator votes, say:

```
   |--------|-------|
   |<Non-Mod>|<Mod> |
   |+5------|+6-----|
   |-2------|-3-----|
   |________________|
```

I think that this should be the case because moderators (on average) most likely know better than the average user what a good question for SO is. Moderators are also less likely to hold a grudge than the average user (this is based on my very limited experience, feel free to comment if you believe otherwise), as they can get their rights revoked. While the average user might just go around downvoting things because they dislike a certain user, moderators are less likely to do so. The reason why I do not suggest more influential votes on answers is because mods aren't necessarily smarter, hence they don't neccessarily grade answers better (compared to the average user).

Taking BillTheLizard's suggestion, maybe every upvote you give...you get 1 rep?

Comment: `Moderators are also less likely to hold a grudge than the average user` - you've never met casperOne, have you...

Comment: I have not, what did he do?

Comment: he didn't do anything - he's a good moderator - twas just a joke :)

Comment: Since this is your first post here I'll just mention that downvotes on your question only mean that people disagree with this idea.  That's all.  Please don't take it personally (as many people here do).

Comment: I +1 this question. I do not agree with the idea (see animuson's answer) but I support the general idea of appreciating the implied quality of the mods as SO users.

Comment: `While the average user might just go around downvoting things because they dislike a certain user` Nope, a user can't really do that, regular or mod. There's a script detecting such patterns and reverses serial voting (either up or down) and if they do it repeatedly they might find themselves suspended.

Answer (score 14):

That will just add another thing people can come here to meta to complain about.

> Why is the moderator voting for this user's stuff and not mine? Abuse of powers!

So then people try to propose guidelines that moderators have to follow for voting on things and soon they're not even voting on things they think are good, they're just casting random votes to be "fair" and they can't even enjoy the community anymore.

Moderators already have enough to worry about. They don't need the added hassle of having more weight when it comes to voting nor the headaches that would come with it.

Comment: Your last sentence was my first thought. I agree with the rest too, of course.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure we all appreciate the vote of confidence, but no thanks.  There are some areas where moderators should just continue to be treated like every other member of the community.  Asking and answering questions and voting are among those.

Now if you have any ideas on how to encourage *everyone else* to vote a little more, we'd love to hear them.  :)

Answer (score 1):

On *some* level, this already exists.

A moderator *close vote* is powerful enough to immediately close a question while it takes five 3K+ users to do the same with *their* close votes...

Recent example of a post that was closed by five 3K+ users :
[Where is the Stack Overflow I joined two years ago?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128462/where-is-the-stack-overflow-i-joined-two-years-ago)

Recent example of a post that was closed with a diamond moderators super close vote :
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128476/what-to-do-with-rep-in-the-real-world

As you can see in the second example, users had already started voting to close but once a d.mod voted, the post was immediately closed.

Answer (score 0):

This will complicate problem more and i think its just making things more complicating.
And it will rise more question about moderators power and all. So i think same voting power for all are good thing.