# The [poll] tag is used for too many topics, needs reorganization

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, clean-up

<sup>*Note that this is not about [[polls] questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107518/lets-burninate-blacklist-the-polls-tag).*</sup>

Looking through the 120 or so questions tagged [poll](/questions/tagged/poll), there seems to be a wide range of topics it's used for.

1. [`poll()` (usually with `[c]` questions)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)
2. [Java's `Queue#poll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll%28%29)
3. [PrimeFaces `p:poll` tag](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.2/p/poll.html)
4. [Sitecore poll module](http://www.codehousegroup.com/services/sitecore-modules/sitecore-quick-poll)
5. [RichFaces `a4j:poll` tag](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_poll.html)
6. [Drupal Advanced Poll module](http://drupal.org/project/advpoll)
7. Solving a problem using a polling strategy
8. Creating a piece of software that polls users (i.e. asks questions)
9. Using the Facebook API to create a poll/question

We ought to disambiguate this tag. Before I go on a massive re-tagging spree, I'd be interested in community input on how we should re-tag these, and which one most deserves to own the `[poll]` tag itself.

I've done a fair amount of investigation already and have come up with some suggestions. I've split them up into separate answers below since it'd be difficult to get accurate and specific feedback if they were all lumped into a single answer. I welcome other answers with alternative suggestions. <sub>*Chuckles at the notion of creating poll-like answers to a question about questions tagged [poll].*</sub>

If consensus is reached I'll go and update tag wikis and re-tag where appropriate.

Comment: The only actual peril I see with the [poll] tag is its possible use for creating a poll question.  Your first six bullets can be disambiguated as [poll-method], [queue-poll], [primefaces-poll], [sitecore-poll], [richfaces-poll], and [drupal-poll], assuming they need disambiguating at all (you *can* use multiple tags in a search, y'know.  You can even get an RSS feed for the tag set).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Yeah, I saw the potential for misuse / misunderstanding as well. The alternative there would be to simply blacklist the `[poll]` tag in favor of the disambiguated ones.

Comment: I honestly don't feel disambiguation is needed, especially for that few questions. As I said, you can use multiple tags in a search, as in [primefaces] [poll]

Comment: @RobertHarvey - We can just leave questions for #1-6 alone. I think there may still need to be a re-tagging effort for #7 and #8, though. #9 I'm still unsure about.

Comment: I've listed this in [The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012) - If you'd update that post when complete (for the appropriate tag), it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Questions for solving a problem using a polling strategy should use the [polling](/questions/tagged/polling) tag. It has a number of questions already and most of them seem to be of this type.

Comment: Agreed.  I added a tag wiki.

Answer (score 2):

For creating Facebook polls, we should create a new tag: [facebook-questions](/questions/tagged/facebook-questions). Facebook has API documentation for its Questions interface.

*There might be some confusion by non-observant (i.e. lazy) users who think that this tag means "I have a question about Facebook."*

Comment: Facebook already has the [facebook] tag, and it's own URL.  That's not enough?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I'm okay with removing it too. I don't frequent the `[facebook]` tags much, so my opinion's rather uninformed. I could see these questions being retagged under `[facebook-graph-api]`, too.

Comment: So there's something called "Facebook Polls?" Sheesh.

Answer (score 1):

[poll](/questions/tagged/poll) should be used for `poll()` questions (i.e. linux file event polling). They seem to be the majority of the existing tagged questions.

*The only potential issue here is that new users who don't read the tag wiki may continue use [poll] for unrelated questions.*

Answer (score 1):

For the questions about creating a poll-style application (i.e. asking users questions / voting), I'm inclined to just un-tag them.

One alternative would be to tag them with something like [user-polls] or [voting], but those still feel too vague.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following types of questions probably don't need a [poll] tag of any kind - the subject (e.g. PrimeFaces) tag would probably be enough:

- Java's `Queue#poll()`
- PrimeFaces `p:poll` tag
- Sitecore poll module
- Drupal Advanced Poll module

There aren't really that many of these types of questions, anyway.