# Please restore the poll tag

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

There used to be a [poll](/questions/tagged/poll) tag on Stack Overflow, which covered the [`poll`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/poll.html) family of I/O functions on unix-like systems.

This tag has disappeared, and cannot be re-created because the [polls](/questions/tagged/polls) tag already exists.

Please re-create the tag ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029910/gcc-on-hp-ux-lots-of-poll-pipe-and-file-issues) is an example of a question that should have been tagged [poll](/questions/tagged/poll) and not [polls](/questions/tagged/polls)).

Since the tag [polls](/questions/tagged/polls) is rather unnatural on this question, I suspect that this was the result of a bad merge. This is unfortunate: we have a bunch of legitimate questions that were unwittingly thrown together with a tag that signals questions that should be deleted. Developers: is it possible to undo this merge?

Arguably, [poll](/questions/tagged/poll) is prone to confusion. Would [poll-function](/questions/tagged/poll-function) be a reasonable tag name? Any other suggestion?

Comment: I wonder that the `polls` tag exists at all. Most (if not all) of the questions tagged as such should be closed as `not constructive`.

Comment: Related: [The \[poll\] tag is used for too many topics, needs reorganization](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128709/the-poll-tag-is-used-for-too-many-topics-needs-reorganization)

Comment: @Felix - the tag is probably a very early one, from when polls were tolerated.

Comment: @ChrisF: I thought so too. Still, I wonder why it was not cleaned up yet :)

Comment: @Felix - sheer volume of questions. It takes time to go through 400+ questions to check whether it needs closing or not, retagging if appropriate etc. All the while new questions could be being added.

Comment: There's been some recent work on this tag as part of [The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Comment: @animuson I'm told developers can unmerge a tag, but with difficulty; there may not be so many questions that it's worth the trouble for them. Do not remove the [tag:feature-request] since I am requesting at least the creation of the [tag:poll] tag.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I know; it looks like something was botched as part of that process, which is why I'm starting a separate thread for this issue.

Comment: @Gilles: If that's the case, then it can simply fall under the existing [meta-tag:retag-request] tag, which also explained that when requesting moderator (or dev) assistance with tags, you should use [meta-tag:support].

Comment: @animuson That's not what I was told when I became a mod, and I applied on the metas where I mod. Support is asking a question, feature request is asking for intervention.

Comment: Why can't these questions fall under the category of `[polling]`?

Comment: @Gilles: I'm not familiar with other site's metas because I don't really participate much on other metas, but that's how it's long been done *here*.

Comment: @TheEstablishment - IMO `[polling]` ought to be for solutions involving general, polling-strategy questions (e.g. polling with javascript, or something). [I had that as an option here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128713/132734), but I'm not sure my question got a lot of visibility, and therefore not much feedback on whether or not other people agree/disagreee.

Answer (score 15):

There are many valid functions named 'poll' to which this tag could be applied.  I suggest that the most common and best application of the tag would be the Posix function [`poll(3)` (link)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/poll), but I don't think it's sufficient to call it [poll-function](/questions/tagged/poll-function) because no one reads the tag wikis.

Therefore, I suggest that the new tag name be [posix-poll](/questions/tagged/posix-poll).  This would be difficult to confuse with anything else, and other languages or APIs with a function by this name can have their own tag.

Comment: 100% agreed.  Repurposing a vague and abused tag isn't a good idea when we have clearer alternatives.

Comment: I disagree with [tag:posix-poll]. Most users of this tag are programming for Linux and may not even know what POSIX is. *Maybe* with synonyms for [tag:linux-poll] and [tag:unix-poll], but it looks weird even then.

Comment: @Gilles `polling`, as suggested in the comments on the question, seems like the right choice to me, as long as it has a very clear "NOT FOR POLLS" notice in the tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: @Gilles if there would be two synonym tags, `poll-function` and `posix-poll`, would that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @gnatakaspecialagentMulder As I understand it, the objection to [tag:poll-function] is that there are other platforms with an unrelated function called `poll`. If so, this is a valid objection against having a [tag:poll-function] tag altogether. Kevin: what common OS/framework has an unrelated function called `poll`?

Comment: We would then have to re-tag everything tagged `epoll` (currently 31 questions) to be `posix-epoll` as well.

Comment: Ugh, we also need to take a close look at where `select` is being used (currently 1,069 questions, many don't discuss `select()`).

Comment: @Gilles - For starters, [here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#poll()) a poll function in Java, and [here's](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21poll%21poll.module/7) a Drupal module.  It's a short verb and noun which is related to a task common in programming; I don't think my claim needs an exhaustive reference.  I think it's as ambiguous as, say, [tag:print-function], [tag:push-function] or [tag:open-function].  Or [tag:select], for that matter.

Comment: @KevinVermeer That `poll` method in Java isn't tag material, people would use the class name. The Drupal module is a better argument. There's nothing wrong with [tag:print], [tag:push] or [tag:open] to indicate functions by these names, to go alongside a language tag and possibly other tags.