# How to add "poll" tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please restore the poll tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130866/please-restore-the-poll-tag)

I wanted to add the [poll](/questions/tagged/poll) tag to [a question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905537/should-all-linux-applications-never-place-blocking-file-desciptors-to-select-pol). I did however get the following message:

```
Creating the new tag [poll] is not allowed since the tag 
[polls] already exists. If you think this new tag should 
be allowed, raise it on meta.
```

My question is not about polls, but about the poll(2) syscall. How can I tag it properly?

Comment: What about poll-syscall?

Comment: A [poll] tag will definitely get misused; you probably want some other name

Comment: I would use tags [tag:polling] + [tag:syscall] or [tag:poll-syscall]

Comment: It seems that every time this comes up, someone proposes an even less discoverable tag name as a workaround.

Comment: Now using "poll-syscall" and "select-syscall". Hoping it will be discoverable and other questions will use them too.