# What just happened to this question?

Tags: support

[Manager versus Developer as a career](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389833/)

Has the OP's account been hacked?

Comment: To me it looks like someone doesn't want this question on his public record. Note that the edit has since been reverted.

Comment: Closed recently, but surprisingly not migrated to programmers.

Comment: @tvanfosson: I'm not sure if Anna or Chris would like to see it over there. It smells like a highly subjective career question which does not have a place on PR, too.

Comment: @PaddedCell I agree it's subjective and not a particularly good question, but it's still a better fit for programmers.  I think it would fall under the "business concerns" area listed in the FAQ. Perhaps move AND close are in order.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Move and Close? What do you mean?

Comment: @PaddedCell migrate it to programmers and close it there.

Comment: @tvanfosson: [I don't think they'll be happy with that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but it appears he does not want anything to do with that off topic question.

So now our dear friend anonymous owns it.

Comment: The OP (anon) deleted his account, or just disassociated this specific question from his account somehow?

Comment: I dissociated it, not worth the fight, Jeff would have probably deleted

Comment: @waffles: He did.

Answer (score 1):

The poor question has [long history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/389833/revisions) - the OP probably got "fed up" with all the moderators messing with his post and as he failed to delete it, he did the next best thing he could.

Personally  I agree with the decision to close the question as Off Topic instead of Not Constructive, but can also understand the OP point of view.