# On which Stack Exchange site should I ask about Apple developer relations?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I've recently posted two questions to do with Apple Developer Relations on Stack Overflow. One was fine and got a good answer which I accepted (the question also got an upvote). The other question was voted to close as off topic by 4 people, so I decided to delete it.

On which Stack Exchange site (if any) would it be appropriate to ask questions about developing for a specific company e.g. Apple (or in particular using their developer system)?

Comment: Can we have some example questions?

Comment: Do your questions fit within the scope of what is described at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#questions?

Comment: @N.N. - actually programmers might be that site. Interestingly enough everyone who voted to close my last question voted as "off topic" not "off topic; belongs on programmers"...

Comment: @AlexCoplan Ok, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) may be appropriate for you question. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#questions for their scope.

Answer (score 1):

After [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) was posted, I've seen far fewer votes to migrate questions to [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), and I've been more discerning about voting to migrate questions to other sites.

If the question is good but just in the wrong place, I'll vote to migrate. If I think the core of the question is good but it needs more detail, I'll vote to migrate *and* ask in comments for the question to be improved. If I've got doubts that the question can be improved before enough other votes for migration pile on, I'll probably just vote to close the question.

I can't speak for those who actually voted on your question -- but I hope it helps understand why your questions may not have been migrated.