# How long does it take for migration-flags to be processed?

Tags: support, review, flags, migration

A week ago, I flagged [my own fresh question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14756472/974555) for migration to Programmers SE after realising that it fits better there than on Stack Overflow, and soon after the question was closed on Stack Overflow for being off-topic. Ten minutes after I flagged it, the flag was [deemed helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/974555). In the 8 days since then, nothing has happened.

Is there a big backlog for moderators to handle flags? If yes, how large is this backlog, and how long does it normally take for a moderator to decide to migrate or not? If no, what is the current status of my post — flag deemed helpful, several people upvoted [the comment proposing to migrate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756472/strategy-for-keeping-up-with-python-language-changes#comment20653180_14756472), but nothing has happened since?

Comment: Us non-mods cannot see your flag status, btw. No point in linking us to it.

Comment: [We are somewhat reluctant to migrate on that path.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)  It was only eventually migrated because a user with high rep on [programmers.se] flagged and requested migration.

Answer (score 4):

If the flag was marked as helpful, then a moderator already handled it, but the migration request was declined.

Migration-by-moderator involves consultation with the target site, and a close look at the quality of a post. The target site moderators have a say in the migration, they can decline the migration if they feel the question is not of sufficient standard.

Comment: Hmm. I think the communication to the OP could be improved then, because that's not clear at all from the information I can see.

Comment: I've asked on [Meta Programmers SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5553/47323) if/why it was rejected there.

Comment: @gerrit I got my flag declined - which I've posted for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Well, looking at my flagging history (as I also suggested a migration) I got the following response:

> 5 Strategy for keeping up with Python language changes [closed] 1
>   more suited for programmers – Feb 7 at 17:09   declined - Not really, no.

So that could be a reason...