# appropriate place to ask if a certain UI widget/metaphor actually exists and if so what it is called

Tags: support, site-recommendation

EDIT: I could rephrase the question: is there a simple **list** of StackExchange sites with a description of each site's focus, that one can consult in order to find the site most suitable for a question like the following:

I'd like to know where to ask a question like this:

In the world of paper lists, one often sees alphabetized lists presented in columns like this:

```
COLUMN1............COLUMN2..........COLUMN3

aardvark           aquafer          avalanche
abstraction        arrest           axiom
alimony            assiduous        azalea
anemone            atavism           
apricot            authentic       
-----------------------------------------------
```

Finite page depth.
The words "snake" up and down the page in the columns.
If there are more words than can fit on a page, a new page is created.

Does such a snakey pager UI widget exist for HTML5?

Comment: Come on. What stackoverflow site is suited for this? It's not a programming question per se, so it would be rejected on stackoverflow.com, although presumably it would offer an API.   I can't seem to ask an intelligent question on this meta site, despite four years of college and five years of graduate school, and decades of real-word experience. Someone always takes issue with the question, and does not have the courtesy to explain why. This site is perhaps the most discourteous site (passive aggressively) I've ever encountered.

Comment: You may try asking this on ['Programmers'](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) (Check their [On Topic](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section).

Comment: Since you're asking about a user interface metaphor (but since I don't know if it'd be on-topic for UX, you might ask in [their chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/389/ux-chat)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try.

Comment: UX looks promising, @ChrisForrence. Appreciated.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/165773)**. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: @gnat I can't see from what you linked, in which way the OP's question would be OT on Programmers.SE. Could you elaborate on particular points? (I'm not well versed with Programmers.SE conventions and habits though)

Comment: Programmers SE isn't really concerned about the user experience, or even the programming experience as a task that takes a programmer (valuable) time to complete. Programmers SE is more about the pros and cons of various algorithmic approaches to particular classes of problems, from a machine-efficiency perspective, or from an aesthetic perspective, i.e. the more "elegant" solution.

Comment: And FWIW, both parts of your question would be off-topic on Programmers.  "Name that thing" questions generally don't fare well, and resource requests (ie. existing HTML5 widget) fare exceedingly poorly on the site.

Answer (score 1):

No, a simple list like that doesn't exist.  Truth be told, I don't think a simple list like that is all that feasible<sup>1</sup>.

What you can do though is to start with the [SE listing of all of their sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic).

But you'll want to check each sites `/tour`/ and `/help/on-topic` pages to make sure that your question fits.

Understandably, that can be difficult as each site has nuances to their rules that aren't immediately evident from those pages.  Asking on their Meta sites or their chat rooms is the next option to consider if it isn't immediately apparent if your question is on topic.

From there, if you do decide to ask your question then you should hang around and watch for any comments that come in.  Even though the question is clear to you, it may not be clear to others.  Most community members are pretty good about leaving comments that indicate what may be missing or if your question really is off-topic.  Read those comments and do your best to fix any issues they point out.

<sup>1</sup><sub>StackExchange isn't necessarily geared towards making it easy to find the right site to ask your question.  And in some cases there is overlap between site scope - for example, look at StackOverflow and Programmers with regards to design type questions.  Simple lists of site scope don't adequately capture those nuances.</sub>