# What should we do about *identical* cross-site duplicates? (i.e., copy-and-paste cross-posting)

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

In principle, asking a question on multiple sites is fine, since each site has a different community that will probably answer the question in a different way. If the user is consciously choosing to cross-post for that reason, as evidenced by them taking the time to phrase the question differently on each site, then it's fine. [I've even told people to do this before](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7106).

But then there are about the lazy, spammy kind of cross-posts where a user is clearly copy and pasting their entire question from one SE to another simply because they think more posts equals more attention. Often, these cross-posts are on-topic on both sites, and poorly written but probably salvageable, so **none of the usual close/migration reasons apply** (which is why this isn't a duplicate of all the existing meta questions about cross-posting). All we can do is downvote if the question itself is bad and add a comment that cross-posts are frowned upon.

What is the right way to handle these posts?

- Are both communities obliged to help? Since it is *exactly* the same question that would mean a lot of duplication of effort.
- Should the site that's "slightly less on-topic" close or ignore it and let the "more on-topic" site deal with it? I fear this might be our de facto behavior on PSE right now.
- Or should we have some auto-detection that simply looks at what the user has already posted today and warns him that we dislike cross-posting? From what I've seen these cross-posts are from the kind of newbie that might actually listen to a warning.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally the question should be simply closed on the site where it's off topic (or least on topic). If there are no answers on that site then this is straightforward. If there are answers then this involves coordination between the mods to migrate and then merge the questions. Not impossible, but a pain.

For the most post it should be easy to spot which site is most appropriate for a question, but on occasion - especially on sites where there is considerable overlap - it can be hard. The thing to do here is ask the OP which site they want the question on.

A word of warning though - most of these cross site duplicates arise because some well meaning soul spots a question on Stack Overflow (say) and thinks "this would be better on Programmers (say)". However, there's no migration route from Stack Overflow to Programmers ([for good reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)) so they think "I know I'll be helpful and suggest that the question would be better off over there". It's this action that leads to the cross posting of questions - **SO DON'T DO IT**.

If you spot a question that would be better off on site X and there's no migration path flag it for moderator attention and we'll take a look. It might take a little while to get to on some sites (Stack Overflow springs to mind here) but it will get actioned eventually.