# Trying to find correct site to ask how I can find HTML snippets

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm trying to find the correct exchange to ask a question about HTML snippets. I'm trying to find a library of eCommerce snippets to help with a site I'm designing.

Stack Overflow has already closed my question and Web Applications doesn't take development questions.

Comment: Try Programmers.SE.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 such questions are _extremely_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487 **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)**

Comment: Is there a web designers exchange?

Comment: @Gaz_Edge can you provide a link to your StackOverflow question?

Comment: I've deleted as was getting hammered with down votes!!

Comment: @Gaz_Edge UserExperience.SE might work, but I don't know your exact question.

Comment: "find a library of eCommerce snippets", this is a recommendation request, the kind of thing described in [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) - these are generally off-topic across all of the sites. I urge you to read the blog post to try and understand why that is.

Answer (score 2):

That question is a bad fit. SE has a strict policy on recommendation questions since they tend to attract spam or just end up with a list of poor answers.

Stack Overflow or Programmers.SE are definitely not the place to go. With a good set of requirements you might get an answer on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but make sure to read their [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to know if your question is a good fit there.

Comment: +1 although not all SE sites yet accept that strict policy, more's the pity: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/3660/115