# Which Stack Exchange site is preferred to ask about certifications?

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation

I have some questions about [Cisco certifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_certifications) (like [CCIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCIE_Certification) and [CCNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCNA)). So which Stack Exchange site is preferred to ask about these things?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*(Here I explain, why he **can't** post it anywhere)*

Well, this is a hard thing. The main problem that SE sites tend to interpret their topicality as narrow as possible, and it tends to worsen with time. Although sometimes there are also possitive changes, I suspect mainly CM effect behind that and not the "natural" change of the community.

Your question seems to me a border case on many sites, which means it can be accepted manywhere, but nowhere has a big chance. The sites I would suggest:

- http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com . They have very strict and narrow topicality, despite their urge to grow. But maybe a little bit of previous consultation on their meta could help.
- http://programmers.stackexchange.com . Here the main problem is that it is not a programming question, maybe with programming-related certificates you would have more chance.
- http://serverfault.com . They also have a similarly strict policy as the networkengineering.
- http://academia.stackexchange.com . Here the main problem that they are focusing to post-grad matters and not to out-of-academia certifications as yours.
- http://workplace.stackexchange.com . Here you can find answer on workplace and jobsearch-related things, I suspect maybe at least some of your questions would fall in this category.

---

*(From here I explain, what possible roundabouts and partial solutions I can see)*

There is also the surprisingly unused [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com), most of the sites have one. On the chatrooms, you can get answers to questions which are considered offtopic on the main site, but seem answerable by their power users. Most SE sites have a dedicated chat room for that.

Chat can be used also to consultation before or after the question, often it is possible that actually you *can* ask the question on a form, which passes the site review mechanism while you also get an answer to your question. For example, most sites actually *allow* asking your homework questions there, but the requirements in this matter are hard to pass. If the homework OPs would consult about this on the meta or in the chat, most of them could formulate their question to an acceptable form (or even get an answer there). Most of them simply won't do this. Maybe you can find a similar way also in your case.

It would be also possible to initiate a new site in the Area51, but it will be slow and it hasn't a quite high chance. From the other side, it would make possible for many people with similar problems as you to get their answers to their questions similar to yours.

It is also very important: the topic of the sites results, that you will get your answers in *their* viewpoint. Thus, for example, "What can I learn on a course of an XXX Cisco cert" can be more near to the topic of the networkengineering, while a question like "How the HR estimate the worth of an XXX Cisco cert in the selection process" may match much better the workplace SE. Thus, fragmenting your question and ask them differently on different sites is an useful strategy. You can also link your related questions on other sites in comments.

Most of the meta sites tend to behave like a fight club between the question closer community and the asker/defender community, thus initiating something on the meta will most likely result a long thread in negative tone. Remain always polite, and don't forget: your goal is to know, *how can you ask your question in an acceptable form*. Don't react to the attacks, it is much better if you try to move the discussion into a consultant line: how could it be asked on a conform way, what is the part of your question which is acceptable, etc.

Comment: I think SE sites tend to determine what is on-topic as naturally as possible.

Comment: @PolyGeo The sites are quite different in this sense, I don't know the GIS and the Genealogy SE, but I wish you have right in the case of these sites. Between the sites in my combined flair, I think SU, SO and MathSE does this what you say, while the SF and the Physics SE does its exact opposite. For example, on Unix SE you can't ask about Unix programming, or on Serverfault you can't ask about a broad range of remote management tools. These are totally illogical decisions from their side in my opinion, leading to continous troubles and harassment of goodstanding newbies.

Comment: these questions are _extremely_ poor fit for Programmers - they would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Why do certification questions keep getting closed?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6443/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat I explained the OP, why his question has only a small chance on the programmers SE. And you now "correct" me, of course with a downvote, explaining that his question has only a small chance on the programmers :-) Thank you very much, I had always the impression, that the PSE isn't my community, thank you very much the additional proof :-)

Comment: yeah sure. It's just the thing for Programmers to get [hundreds lemmings from Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) to try their luck over there. "Oh but I found this at meta, and it says 'maybe with programming-related certificates you would have more chance'". I guess you didn't even look at Programmers meta posts referred in my prior comment

Comment: @gnat Exactly. I am not interested on the inner circle orgies explaining why they *need* to reduce their topic. By you, it is a ritual: a monkey initiates, "let X be offtopic", and then you all explain, *yeeees it should be offtopic*, and then you love eachother, everybody votes everybody up, and then close&destruct together a lot of goodstanding newbie questions. I simply didn't want to see it 345354. time, so is it.

Comment: On a closed question (as off-topic), *[NPDEV software defined networking Cisco certification](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24028)*, from 2015 on Network Engineering, a moderator commented: *"NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. The community has decided that certification/education questions are off topic. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details."*. So Network Engineering seems to be out of the question.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Around a half of the answer was about the roundabouts or partial answers (chat, meta). For example, about a factual question in the exam to this cert, even the NE could help. Or, maybe the OP could find informal, out-of-the Q&A answers trying on the chat. You, gnat and the downvoters simply ignored this. It looks as if you had interpreted the post as an advice to post a question on these sites.

Comment: @gnat My previous comment is also for you.

Comment: I extended the answer to help the downvoters of the future easier to understand, that I actually *didn't* advice the OP to post offtopic questions anywhere.